# Read Data from a CSV file

Tags: c#, wpf, csv

I am looking to store values from a CSV file with two Columns, I have the following class `ReadFromCSV`handling the reading of the CSV file but I am having difficulty using this list to display the contents once a button is clicked. The code I have to read the CSV file is as follows;

```
namespace ELMFS
{
    public class ReadFromCSV
    {
        static void ReadCSV(string[] args)
        {
            List<TextSpeak> TxtSpk = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\textwords.csv")
                .Skip(1)
                .Select(t => TextSpeak.FromCsv(t))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
    public class TextSpeak
    {
        string Abreviated;
        string Expanded;


        public static TextSpeak FromCsv(string csvLine)
        {
            string[] TxtSpk = csvLine.Split(',');
            TextSpeak textSpeak = new TextSpeak();
            textSpeak.Abreviated = TxtSpk[0];
            textSpeak.Expanded = TxtSpk[1];
            return textSpeak;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to display the `textSpeak.Abreviated` in a message box but cannot seem to access it from the `WPF window`.

How do I use this list in other windows within the application?

any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ReadCSV method should return the generated List object (or you cannot use the list anywhere else).

Second, TextSpeak class should have properties so that you can access its member variables outside the class.

I.e. something like this should work:

```
namespace ELMFS
{
    public class ReadFromCSV
    {
        public static List<TextSpeak> ReadCSV(string[] args)
        {
            List<TextSpeak> TxtSpk = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\textwords.csv")
                .Skip(1)
                .Select(t => TextSpeak.FromCsv(t))
                .ToList();
            return TxtSpk;
        }
    }
    public class TextSpeak
    {
        public string Abreviated { get; private set; }
        public string Expanded { get; private set; }


        public static TextSpeak FromCsv(string csvLine)
        {
            string[] TxtSpk = csvLine.Split(',');
            TextSpeak textSpeak = new TextSpeak();
            textSpeak.Abreviated = TxtSpk[0];
            textSpeak.Expanded = TxtSpk[1];
            return textSpeak;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Display(int count)
        {

            textBox1.Text = "";
            for (int i = 0; i <= count ; i++)
            {
                textBox1.Text += ((dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value).ToString()) +  (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine;

            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                // your code here 

                string CSVFilePathName =Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath).Replace(@"\bin\Debug", @"\NewFolder1\TEST.csv");
                string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(CSVFilePathName);
                string[] Fields;
                Fields = Lines[0].Split(new char[] { ',' });
                int Cols = Fields.GetLength(0);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                //1st row must be column names; force lower case to ensure matching later on.
                for (int i = 0; i < Cols; i++)
                    dt.Columns.Add(Fields[i].ToLower(), typeof(string));
                DataRow Row;
                for (int i = 1; i < Lines.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
                    Row = dt.NewRow();
                    for (int f = 0; f < Cols; f++)
                        Row[f] = Fields[f];
                    dt.Rows.Add(Row);
                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                int count = 0;

                if (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0)
                {

                    count = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
                }


                buttons  = new Button[count];
                for (int i = 0; i <count; i++)
                {
                    buttons[i] = new Button();
                    buttons[i].Name = "buttons_Click" + i.ToString();
                    buttons[i].Text = "Click";
                    buttons[i].Click += new EventHandler(buttons_Click);
                    this.Controls.Add(buttons[i]);
                    buttons[i].Visible = false;
                }

                buttons[0].Visible = true;
               // buttons[1].Visible = true;

            }


            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error is " + ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
        private void buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count = dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1;
            if(c <= count)
            {

                if (buttons[c].Name == "buttons_Click" + c.ToString())
                {
                    buttons[c].Visible = false;
                    int j = c;
                    Display(j);
                    if (c != count)
                    {

                        c = c + 1;
                        buttons[c].Visible = true;
                    }

                }

            }
            if (c == count)
            {
                buttons[0].Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation of your code would be much more helpful than just a code snippet by itself.